# Network unclaimed and internet is not working?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have just installed Linux Mint on my laptop Dell Vostro, but networking is not working - I am getting a "-network UNCLAIMED" message when I run lshw.

uname -a

> linux vostro 3.5.0-17 generic
>   x86_64

Typing lshw shows the following:

```
       *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Network controller
            psroduct: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
            vendor: Broadcom corp.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0

        *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Ethernet controller
            psroduct: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
            vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            version: 10
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:f1800000-f183ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

How can I get the network working ?